# Array Buffer Object is disabled

Tags: java, model, arraylist, libgdx

I tried to create 3D cubes that had a xpos, ypos, type and a modelInstance stored in them. When I try to run the program I get this error:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Cannot use offsets when Array Buffer Object is disabled

How do I enable it?

Here is the class I got the error from:

```
package com.me.the_unknown;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.VertexAttributes.Usage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Model;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelInstance;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.materials.Material;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.materials.TextureAttribute;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.ModelBuilder;

public class Blocks {

    public static ArrayList<Float> blockX = new ArrayList<Float>();
    public static ArrayList<Float> blockY = new ArrayList<Float>();
    public static ArrayList<Integer> blockType = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static ArrayList<ModelInstance> blockModelInstance = new ArrayList<ModelInstance>();

    public static ModelBatch modelBatch;
    private static ModelBuilder modelBuilder;

    //Textures
    public static Texture stonebrick = new Texture("data/blocks/stonebrick.png");
    public static Texture gravel = new Texture("data/blocks/gravel.png");

    public static void addBlock(int xpos, int ypos, int type) {
        blockX.add((float) xpos * 5);
        blockY.add((float) ypos * 5);
        blockType.add(type);
        updateBlocks();
    }

    private static void updateBlocks() {
        blockModelInstance.clear();

        for(int counter = 0; counter < blockX.size(); counter++){
            Model model = null;
            ModelInstance instance;

            if(blockType.get(counter) == 1)
                model = modelBuilder.createBox(5f, 5f, 5f, new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(stonebrick)), Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.TextureCoordinates | Usage.Generic);
            if(blockType.get(counter) == 2)
                model = modelBuilder.createBox(5f, 5f, 5f, new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(gravel)), Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.TextureCoordinates | Usage.Generic);

            instance = new ModelInstance(model);
            blockModelInstance.add(instance);

            model.dispose();
        }
    }

    public static void create() {
        modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
        updateBlocks();
    }
}
```

Comment: No stack trace or some hit about what line this exception trigger?

Comment: @Grimmy No, not in my code. But there is this: `at org.lwjgl.opengl.GLChecks.ensureArrayVBOenabled(GLChecks.java:93)` When i click the line number, it says that it doesn't exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a Model, then create a ModelInstance of it and then dispose the Model which practically makes the ModelInstance unusable because it depends on the Model.

Make sure that the Model outlives the ModelInstances that depend on it, as it manages their resources. In your case the ModelInstance will be invalid, because the Mesh it depends on is disposed with the call to model.dispose(), causing the error you got.

Also try to avoid statics, it might cause problems on devices when you app is closed and then restarted again.